# Calling a Stylus {block} with a variable in an iteration

Tags: css, stylus

I'm trying to generate classes with Stylus `{block}` insertions while on an iteration with that code:

```
// Blocks
flexbox =
  display flex

inline-flexbox =
  display inline-flex

// Properties collection
props = {
  'flexbox': 'flex',
  'inline-flexbox': 'inline-flex'
}

// Generating classes 
for kProp, vProp in props
  .u-{vProp}
     {kProp}
```

`{kProp}` is supposed to output `{flexbox}` and `{inline-flexbox}` but I guess there's some kind of syntax conflict between calling a Stylus `{block}` and calling the iteration variable.

So basically with this code, I got no output at all.

I also tried to escape the `{ }` but no luck.

Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

No proper solution but some workarounds I found:

- You can replace `{blocks}` by extending `$placeholders` **but** be aware that with Stylus you can't extend inside a Media Query (it just ignore the MQ part)
- You can simply replace `{blocks}` by `mixins()` (and it works inside Media Queries) which is the one I chose.

So basically now my code looks like this:

```
// Blocks
flexbox()
  display flex

inline-flexbox()
  display inline-flex

// Properties collection
props = {
  'flexbox': 'flex',
  'inline-flexbox': 'inline-flex'
}

// Generating classes 
for kProp, vProp in props
  .u-{vProp}
     {kProp}()
```